# Python doesn't find the modules in my package

Tags: python, import, package

I must be missing something very basic about building a package in Python. When I create a package following the guidelines of https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages and import it, Python does not find any of the modules. For example, say I create the package holygrail with the following structure:

- holygrail/

  - __init__.py
  - knights.py

I leave __init__.py empty because the docs say that I can and I'm just trying to make a basic package to start. In knights.py I have:

```
def say():
     print 'Ni!'
```

If I try `import holygrail`, Python doesn't give any errors, but `holygrail.knights.say()` results in Python telling me that the "'module' object [holygrail] has no attribute 'knights'." However, if I specifically import knights via `from holygrail import knights`, then `knights.say()` works. In addition, `holygrail.knights.say()` then also works.

I tried adding the line

```
__all__  = ['knights']
```

in the __init__.py file, but this did not change the behavior.

How do I construct a package such that `import package` loads in all of the modules, allowing statements like `package.module.function()`?

Comment: put `import knights` in your __init__.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not implicitly import the whole package hierarchy. You have to be explicit about what to import on what level of the package using the `__init__.py` files.

When you set `__all__ = ['knights']` in the `__init__.py` it works only for the *import all* statements for that module, e.g.:

```
>>> import holygrail
>>> holygrail.knights.say()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'knights'

>>> from holygrail import *
>>> knights.say()
Ni!
```

It can also act as a filter on *import all*, importing from the module only what's specified.

To get `knights` automatically imported on `import holygrail` you have to put `import knights` or `from . import knights` ([intra-package or relative import](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)) to the `__init__.py`. You'll have to do the same for every module explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Add `import knights` into `__init__.py`.

The link you provided does state "In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file..." Your example is not the simplest case, that's all.

Comment: This is a bad idea seeing as it says in the Python Zen that explicit is better than implicit. Above is definitely a case of implicit; the user of the package may not want this to happen, it would only 'help' (saving like 10 characters at the expense of making the code harder to read) in this specific case.